# Modifying timezone of a POSIXct object without changing the display

Tags: r, timezone, posixct

I have a `POSIXct` object and would like to change it's `tz` attribute WITHOUT R to interpret it (interpret it would mean to change how the datetime is displayed on the screen).

Some background: I am using the `fasttime` package from S.Urbanek, which take strings and cast it to `POSIXct` very quickly. Problem is that the string should represent a datetime in "GMT" and it's not the case of my data.

I end up with a `POSIXct` object with `tz=GMT`, in reality it is `tz=GMT+1`, if I change the timezone with

```
attr(datetime, "tzone") <- "Europe/Paris";
datetime  <- .POSIXct(datetime,tz="Europe/Paris");
```

then it will be "displayed" as `GMT+2` (the underlying value never change).

EDIT: Here is an example

```
datetime=as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 12:32:23.234",tz="GMT")
attributes(datetime)
#$tzone
#[1] "GMT"
datetime
#[1] "2011-01-01 12:32:23.233 GMT"
```

How can I change this attribute without R to interpret it aka how can I change tzone and still have datetime displayed as `"2011-01-01 12:32:23.233"` ?

EDIT/SOLUTION, @GSee's solution is reasonably fast, lubridate::force_tz very slow

```
datetime=rep(as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 12:32:23.234",tz="GMT"),1e5)
f <- function(x,tz) return(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x), origin="1970-01-01", tz=tz))
> system.time(datetime2 <- f(datetime,"Europe/Paris"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02 
> system.time(datetime3 <- force_tz(datetime,"Europe/Paris"))
   user  system elapsed 
   5.94    0.02    5.98 
identical(datetime2,datetime3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Possibly useful blog post: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html

Comment: `lubridate::force_tz`

Comment: Newer users should note that you can *not* have more than one time zone in a single column in a data.frame.

Comment: Note that your function `f` doesn't correspond to @GSee's latest answer, because the origins won't necessarily be the same. When I do `f(datetime[1], tz="Europe/Paris")` with your `f` I get `2011-01-01 13:32:23 CET`. So in `f` I think you should have `origin = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz=tz)`. Also, `force_tz` appears to be much faster now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### EDITED:

My previous solution was passing a character value to `origin` (i.e.`origin="1970-01-01"`).  That only worked here because of a bug ([#PR14973](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14973)) that has now [been fixed](http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2013/03/30#n2013-03-30) in R-devel.

`origin` was being coerced to `POSIXct` using the `tz` argument of the `as.POSIXct` call, and not `"GMT"` as it was documented to do.  The behavior has been changed to match the documentation which, in this case, means that you have to specify your timezone for both the `origin` and the `as.POSIXct` call.

```
datetime
#[1] "2011-01-01 12:32:23.233 GMT"
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(datetime), origin=as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz="Europe/Paris"),
           tz="Europe/Paris")
#[1] "2011-01-01 12:32:23.233 CET"
```

This will also works in older versions of R.

Comment: Will that do what the OP wants? What about differences in daylight saving between timezones? I can see that a datetime in DST in one time zone would get displayed an hour off when converted a different time zone that wasn't in DST at that point.

Comment: DST shouldn't matter because the original time is GMT (which doesn't have DST), and the goal is to keep the time the same and just pretend like it's a different timezone, IIUC

Comment: I think that would do it... but this construct a new object, isn't it possible to access the `tz` member without letting R change the way the datetime is displayed ?

Comment: @statquant, you'd think so; I'm having trouble finding a way to do it though.

Comment: You know what it's ok, It is fast enough, I do not know how R is coded internally but you can think that when the `tz` attribute is changed an event is raised so the displayed is changed...so may be it is just not possible

Comment: This solution does work for the pair "GMT", "Europe/Paris" but not for "EST", "UTC" (R-2.15.3, 64bit, Win7). However, `force_tz` gives the correct result.

Comment: @cryo111 You need to read `?timezone`.  "Beware
     that some of these designations may not be what you think: in
     particular ‘EST’ is a time zone used in Canada _without_ daylight savings time, and not ‘EST5EDT’ nor (Australian) Eastern Standard Time."

Comment: You can also replace the pair ("EST","UTC") by ("America/New_York","UTC") - same problem, i.e., for these pairs the displayed time gets changed. BTW: "America/New_York" is automatically translated to "EST" (eastern standard time) if the date is in winter or "EDT" if it is in summer. Indeed, "EST" is without daylight savings time (as expected, see wikipedia). But that is not the problem here. Just try your code with the timezone pairs I have provided. As I have pointed out, `force_tz` gives the correct result.

Comment: @cryo111 I see.  You are correct.  Here's an alternate way which is part of what lubridate is doing, I think: `x <- as.POSIXlt(datetime); attr(x, "tzone") <- "UTC"; as.POSIXct(x)`

Comment: Cool! Works as far as I can say. The whole timezone conversion issue seems to be a bit of a mess in R. However, I do not know whether this is a problem with R or me not digging deep enough into the matter. But I guess it's the latter. :)

Answer (score 17):

To change the `tz` attribute of a `POSIXct` variable it is not best practice to convert to character or numeric and then back to `POSIXct`. Instead you could use the `force_tz` function of the `lubridate` package

```
library(lubridate)

datetime2 <- force_tz(datetime, tzone = "CET")
datetime2
attributes(datetime2)
```

Comment: nope, I meant to change the `tz` attribute without changing the way the datetime is displayed

Comment: Ah ok, I changed the answer. It's quite easy with the lubridate package.

Comment: damn it's very slow, see my EDIT !

Comment: `lubridate:::force_tz` is slow because it's making at least 7 calls to `as.POSIXlt`!  I'm guessing you say that it is not best practice to convert to numeric and back because of what [looks like a bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14973#c2).  If that is not a bug then you may have a point; otherwise, POSIXct objects are already numeric, so converting to POSIXlt (a list) several times is certainly not best practice.

Comment: You are right, but besides that I think it is less error-prone. By that I mean you can easily make a mistake when specifying the origin.

Comment: After looking closer, `force_tz` converts the input to `as.POSIXlt`, then makes the subsequent `as.POSIXlt` calls on the `POSIXlt` object -- so it's not converting from numeric to list several times which is good.  There's still lots of method dispatch overhead, but it's definitely better than I thought at first glance.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to the `lubridate` package is via conversion to and back from character type:

```
recastTimezone.POSIXct <- function(x, tz) return(
  as.POSIXct(as.character(x), origin = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01"), tz = tz))
```

(Adapted from GSee's answer)

Don't know if this is efficient, but it would work for time zones with daylight savings.

Test code:

```
x <- as.POSIXct('2003-01-03 14:00:00', tz = 'Etc/UTC')
x
recastTimezone.POSIXct(x, tz = 'Australia/Melbourne')
```

Output:

```
[1] "2003-01-03 14:00:00 UTC"
[1] "2003-01-03 14:00:00 AEDT" # Nothing is changed apart from the time zone.
```

Output if I replaced `as.character()` by `as.numeric()` (as GSee had done):

```
[1] "2003-01-03 14:00:00 UTC"
[1] "2003-01-03 15:00:00 AEDT" # An hour is added.
```

Comment: This was the best answer for me on this page. I don't originally have my times in POSIXct format, so I can use something like  `as.POSIXct(datetime.character.format, format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M", tz = "EST5EDT", origin = "1970-01-01")`