# Change timezone without changing the actual time

Tags: r, timezone, posixct

I have the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575713/modifying-timezone-of-a-posixct-object-without-changing-the-display. However, I followed the accepted response but I don't get the desired result.

dt is a string (`"2017-07-07 15.46.00"`). I need to change it to data-time format with CDT time zone (`"2017-07-07 15:46:00 CDT"`). I can do it by `lubridate::ymd_hms` and I get my desired result (lub.dt: "2017-07-07 15:46:00 CDT") but it is too slow for my dataset size. I converted dt using `fasttime::fastPOSIXct` which is very fast but the function assumes the input is in 'GMT'. So I used 'GMT' for the output as well to get the same date-time display (fast.dt: `"2017-07-07 15:46:00 GMT"`). Finally, I tried to change the time zone by as.POSIXct. I used the same tz (America/Chicago) for origin and the function but I get this result "2017-07-07 16:46:00 CDT" which is (time +1).

```
library(lubridate)
library(fasttime)
dt <- "2017-07-07 15.46.00"
lub.dt <- ymd_hms(dt, tz = 'America/Chicago')
fast.dt <- fastPOSIXct(dt, tz = 'GMT')
fast.dt.new.tz <- as.POSIXct(x = as.numeric(fast.dt), origin = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz = 'America/Chicago'),tz = 'America/Chicago')
```

Can anyone guide me what I did wrong?

Comment: Try just this: `as.POSIXct(dt,"%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S", tz = 'CST6CDT')`.  The CST6CDT should provide the proper CST or CDT time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 'as.POSIXct' is faster than 'lubridate' functions but it's not applicable on my dataset. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247063/is-there-a-fast-parser-for-date) compares different parsing approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This is muddled. Your problem is the insistence on the (very fine) fasttime package, and now trying to fudge the TZ adjustment.

I would recommend against.  You could use anytime which is also pretty fast (compiled code, but tries different formats):

```
R> anytime::anytime("2017-07-07 15.46.00")
[1] "2017-07-07 15:46:00 CDT"
R>
```

It's advantage is that it does what *you* want here: interpret the string as local time, and set the local time (Chicago for me too).

Comment: Thanks Dirk for introducing this package. However, I just checked its performance. It seems it's slower than both 'fastPOSIXct' and 'as.POSIXct'. 'library(microbenchmark)
dt <- "2017-07-07 15.46.00"
test <- rep(dt, 10000)
microbenchmark(
  test1 <- fastPOSIXct(test),
  test2 <- anytime(test),
  test3 <- as.POSIXct(test, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
  times=100)' 
which gives '776, 55940, 3776 ms' respectively.

Comment: Sure. And more general. There are trade-offs.  But it _answers your very question here_.

Comment: Actually it doesn't answer the question. Using `anytime` is not practical on a big dataset. I appreciate if you can help with the last operation (changing the timezone).

Comment: I beg to differ, but if it doesn't suit you luckily there is still the money-back gurantee with open source.  I have another package that shifts timezone but given your attitude I am not exactly motivated in extending this.  Good luck.

Comment: I'm very open to try a new function/approach. But I talked with numbers, `anytime` did the same job about 72 (55940/776) times slower than `fastPOSIX`. I'm not biased to use a function but I usually compare the performance by numbers.

Comment: Apples != oranges.  `fastPOSIX` has a completely different scope ("as fast as possible, one format, only UTC input") where anytime is meant to convert _any_ sane format reasonably fast (using Boost C++ internally).  But as I said, if fast enough + easy + correct is not good enough for you, you are more than welcome to craft your own solution.  I am done here now.